# Who makes androids in the Marvel universe?

Tags: marvel, technology, androids

Which branch of technology in the Marvel universe "makes" androids (for example, Victor Mancha)?

Is their job considered biotechnological, still robotics, or a whole other field of study?

Comment: i edited it, hope you guys get it now :c

Comment: you need to narrow this down to one specific fictional universe/continuity.

Comment: i edited it again, made it specially meaning for the marvel universe

Comment: is this more specific?

Comment: yes.. thats the question i think. like how is the job called of someone who makes androids?

Comment: Evil scientists mostly. Also the occasional non-evil scientist. Superman makes them as well.

Comment: Android makers obviously.

Comment: SHIELD's LMD division (who, it should be noted, did not invent them. The design dates back to the Renaissance apparently)